# PHP recommendation: Inline, internal or external

Tags: php

I'm familiar with PHP, however there's one question that's troubling me:
Is there a convention or general recommendation as to wheter code should be:
-inline, i.e.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php (code to generate content) ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

-internal, i.e.

```
<?php $content=... ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <?= $content ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

-external, i.e.

```
<?php include(...) ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <?= $content ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd say the internal style is better, but I'd like generally accepted conventions or recommendation from organizations.

Comment: Fourth way: separate templates.

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#templating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

You example above looks like a classical template. And following software design patterns like [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you should only have the variables in the HTML and the code to fill/set those variables outside of the template file.

Thus your third example is the one that matches the MVC pattern most.

There might be other use cases, where it can be easier to use inline code in HTML, too.